# PL/pgSQL function with VARCHAR as Parameter

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to write a PL/pgSQL function with a VARCHAR argument, which should be limited. Consider following function, with a VARCHAR parameter limited to a size of 5 characters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_nothin(v_value VARCHAR(5)) 
RETURNS TEXT AS
$$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RETURN v_value;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I call this function with a text bigger than 5, it does work:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    PERFORM do_nothin('123456');
END;
$$
```

It gives me the result '123456', but why? This should give me an error right?

If I define a varchar like this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    v_mytext VARCHAR(5);
BEGIN
    v_mytext := '123456';
END;
$$
```

it gives me an error as expected:

```
 ERROR: value too long for type character varying(5) CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL      function inline_code_block line 5 at assignment SQL state: 22001
```

I want this error thrown when there is a too big argument for the function, but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From historical reasons PostgreSQL ignore size modificator in function argument type (typmod). There are some issues related to implementation and simple and good enough solution is ignore this type feature - the expected behave is simple with varchar, but can be pretty difficult to design correct and user friendly behave for numeric types.

```
create or replace function fx(a varchar(10)) 
returns varchar as $$ begin return a; end $$ language plpgsql;

postgres=# \sf fx
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fx(a character varying)
RETURNS character varying
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ begin return a; end $function$
```

You can see - typmod value is not persistent - and then has not effect.

If you really need some limits, then you should to use `domain type`:

```
postgres=# create domain varchar_10 as varchar(10);
CREATE DOMAIN
postgres=# create or replace function fx2(a varchar_10)
returns varchar as $$ begin return a; end $$ language plpgsql
CREATE FUNCTION
postgres=# select fx2('12345678901');
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(10)
```

Domains are persistent type synonyms with all (typmods, checks).

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#examples) "type modifiers are discarded by `CREATE FUNCTION`".